# What's the best counter for Protoss Carriers?

Tags: starcraft-2

What is the best way to counter a player who is using a lot of Carriers?

Comment: Focus Fire them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The main problem with carriers only really arrives if you allow your opponent to build a ton of them.  Alone, like Carl Clover said, they're very weak.

The secondary problem with carriers is that they're often accompanied by a mothership, which complicates matters.

One of the best ideas to counter a protoss dead-set on going carriers is to scout and provide early pressure if you see him teching quickly to a fleet beacon.  He's probably spending so much money on those buildings that he has a comparatively weak army, and you should be able to do a good deal of damage.

Often the answer to a question of "how do I counter X high tier unit?" isn't so much about countering that unit once it's built, but preventing it from coming out at all.

Comment: Don't let him get that far, is probably the best solution. Make sure he can't expand to get the resources to built them

Comment: Also note that a Viking has a range of 9 while the Carriers only have a range of 8 and they move really slow.

Comment: @Ivo Flipse "don't let him get that far" can't always be the answer.  if the only way to counter a certain unit is to never let the opponent get the unit, then that unit is imbalanced.  SC2 is like rock paper scissors - each unit has a counter.  the important thing is to scout so you know that he has carriers before he shows up with 12 of them and you have a bunch of zerglings or zealots.

Comment: @Peter No Ivo is perfectly right. There are units that can beat a carrier, but once there are 5 carriers you'll need a really big fleet of let's say vikings to take them down. Needless to say that Corruptors and Phoenix are totally worthless as anti-air counters.

If a protoss manages to get to 4-5 carriers there is no possible counter to this. You'll usually have invested in a normal army, not heavily into anti-air so you'll just not have the right mix of units to counter that mount of carriers.

Comment: @Tigraine sorry but that is just not the case.  if you scout him building a fleet beacon, or even scout him with one carrier, you can start building corrupters or hydralisks or vikings or void rays.  by the time the 'toss has 5 carriers, you will have enough anti air to compete.  the point isn't to stop him from getting carriers.  it's to make sure you know he is doing so, and start building the right unit to counter.  i would love to see a replay of 5 carriers destroying an equal amount of corrupters or hydras or even vikings (equal by resource value, not numbers).

Comment: I have to agree that if you let a player get far enough to have a sizable number of carriers, he was going to win anyway. I only build carriers/mothership as an additional insult when I'm already winning, because they really are not cost effective units.

Comment: "don't let them get that far" could be said about any unit though.  If I let my opponent get mass seige tank and I have all anti air, i'm just as screwed.  If I let them get mass marine and all i have is immortals or corrupters or phoenix i am just as screwed.  There is nothing special about carriers that makes 2000 minerals worth of them any scarier than 2000 minerals worth of something else, other than the stupidity of the AI that thinks attacking interceptors is smart.  I just killed 10 carriers in a unit tester with less mineral/gas's worth of corrupters. (i did it with 24 corrupters)

Comment: @Peter Corruptors are dedicated anti-massive attackers, and unless you know the carriers are coming you won't have 24 corruptors to use against them.  "Scout early and provide pressure" are the main points of this answer, because then you'll know what to prepare for.

Comment: My problem, as Terran has been the Toss will build Void Rays as a start and that will keep most of my armies at bay in the first 5-6m. Then they start to throw in a Carrier or two and my army (vikings and marines) seem to melt. I guess the answer is, dont FE if I sense its a high tech play. Course if my attack fails, I am behind in tech. Its a tough strat to counter as Terran

Answer (score 29):

I'm a player who almost always goes for carriers in large games (3v3, 4v4, FFA).

As someone who uses a lot of carriers, I can tell you what I fear the most:

Terran

- Mass Vikings using focus fire. They
  are (way) faster than my carriers,
  and they have longer range. A decent
  number of Vikes can focus-kill a
  carrier in about 1 second.
- Defensively, if you support the Vikings with marines, it's even harder to deal with, since a large group of marines can very quickly kill all my Interceptors.
- Note that marines alone are terrible against carriers. You just can't catch them. Even if you kill my Interceptors, I just run away and rebuild them, or attack you somewhere else. If I've gotten to mass carriers, I probably have the resources to rebuild the Interceptors.

Protoss

- Mass Stalkers with blink. If you don't have blink, forget it, I just run away and pick off the Stalkers that chase. Even with blink, I will try to run away over gaps, but obviously, that's harder than just running away over cliffs.
- Mass (more) Carriers with focus fire.
- Forget Mass Void Rays, UNLESS they are already charged up when the battle starts. Otherwise, by the time they are charged up, half of them will be dead, and game over. Your only chance here is to get into my base and be killing my dudes so that I'm forced to come and engage you while you are charged. Even then, I will come in focus-firing, so you better be ready to react with focus-fire instantly and not waste time killing Interceptors (I see that ALL the time).

Zergling

- Infestors with Fungal Growth, Neural Parasite and Burrow, backed by mutas/hydras/corruptors
- Corruptors WITH corruption, backed by mutas or hydras.
- Corruptors alone aren't usually that effective against Carriers - I can focus fire too, and they're not too hard to run away from. Mutas alone are terrible against carriers, your bounce damage isn't very effective against the mass HP of a carrier. Mass hydras are terrible, I will always just run over a cliff or a gap and attack you somewhere else. However, if you can use fungal growth to freeze Carriers, or corruption to increase damage, and use mutas/hydras/corruptors to pick them off, then i'm in trouble.

Comment: +1 I've definitely had good luck with sentries + stalkers (w/blink) vs. carriers.

Comment: This should be closer to the right answer a combination of this and the main

Comment: tried this approach, but seems like no matter how many stalkers i have opponent picks them off with decent size of carriers + void rays :(  i also tried dark templars + storm.. that helps but i still couldn't beat him..

Comment: +1 for this post not mentioning BCs for Terran. One other option is Thors in High Impact with focus fire - that or have enough Thors that you can literally instantly take out all interceptors but, better off focus firing in HI mode

Answer (score 9):

Since nobody else has mentioned it yet...armor upgrades. The interceptor fires 2 attacks that do 5 damage each unupgraded. With a maximum of 8 interceptors per carrier, *each +1 to armor reduces the total damage the carrier does by 16 per wave of interceptors*. Most anti-air units will do fairly well if you spend an equal amount on them, especially if you can stay ahead in upgrades. Corrupter and vikings are especially effective.

Edit for example: Corrupters start with 2 armor, if your air armor upgrade is one ahead of the carriers' air attack upgrades then each wave of interceptors will do a mere 32 damage (80 - 16 * 3).
If their attack is 1 ahead of your armor, your corrupters instead take 64 damage per wave.

Answer (score 3):

If you are playing zerg, use corrupters, corrupt each carrier, and focus them down.  If they have "a lot" of carriers, they spent a fortune creating them.  If you spend a similar fortune on vikings or corrupters, you should come out OK.
UPDATE:

For example, I just did a test using the Hard Counter map.  10 carriers got killed by 24 corrupters which cost me less minerals and gas. (and quite possibly build time, though that varies with a lot of things)

Answer (score 1):

Carriers are possibly the weakest units in relation to their cost until you have like a dozen of them. Just focus fire them so that you're not wasting firepower on their interceptors.

Comment: As a Terran, this is why its essential to get Thors in High Impact and focus though, I have seen the interceptors melt my Thors

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Carrier

Vikings and corrupters both counter carriers. If anything carriers are under powered.

Comment: Unless you are dealing with 20 of them :)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how many carriers. At 10 carriers there's no straight counter-that's 160 intercepters, the best answer you can get is to run them around, stop them from attacking, keep them on the defensive.

As a Zerg you will want to go mass Hydra, mass corruptor is useless against that much DPS, they fire too slowly. Infestors, especially with their ability to cast their spells burrowed, are fantastic. 
What I'd suggest doing is building a few vipers, abduct what you can without risking your entire army, never take a straight up fight until they're under ~5 carriers. This game will go long, and it will not be fun, your goal is to mine out as many bases as possible without being forced into an engagement-this might mean losing a few bases. Take what buildings of theirs that you can without backing yourself into a corner.

TL;DR, 4+ infesters so that you can fungle Intercepters, killing them with mass hydra, having a few banelings for the mostly-adept ground army they'll certainly have.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you only see mass carrier in team games, like 3v3. So long as you scout early on, it's very easy to beat with the right build.

If I'm protoss, I go straight for a robo and a dark shrine. Most players tech'ing into carriers will cannon the front of their base, and skip getting a robo. So their detection is weak. By the 6 min mark, I have a warp prism in the back of their base warping in DTs. That will usually set their team back enough that we end up overrunning them before they can get mass carriers out.

If I'm zerg, I focus on getting 3 saturated bases, 2 spires and then start cranking out upgraded corrupters. 3/3 corruptors in mass will murder a fleet of carriers. Just be sure to make them focus fire the carriers and not your units shoot at interceptors.

If I'm terran, I usually go for 3 bases and then mass vikings. Fully upgraded mass marine with stim is probably more optimal. I just tend to play better with mech.

I'd be curious if anyone has variants which might work better?

Answer (score -1):

Mass liberators without focus fire murders interceptors very quickly and then they can easily kill the carriers. They win against mass carriers with same upgrades if the army cost the same reseource or the same supply.

Comment: it doesnt look like the carriers have graviton catapults turned on. Now sure how legit this is. Is this HoTS or LoTV?